How to represent a priority constraint in CPLEX Studio using OPL?
I am working on an optimization problem about the WFP where i basically have a set of countries where each contry belongs to a specific region. And each country is also represented by an Emergency Level. R, L2 or L3 (ordered by increasing severity).
I pretty much represented all the constraints for my case study about the World Food Programme. I have but one more constraint I need to represent:
Food baskets can only be distributed to countries in a lower emergency level when at least 60% of the food needs of the countries in the immediately higher emergency level are met.
How can one represent such a constraint in this language in order to solve the problem with CPLEX Studio?
This is my OPL code as of now:
{string} Countries = ...;
{string} Regions = ...;
int Emergency_levels[Regions][Countries] = ...;
int Needs[Regions][Countries] = ...;
int MAX_BASKETS = ...;
int Container_Cost_Transport[Regions] = ...;
int Container_Capacity = ...;
float LG[Regions][Countries] = ...;
float LA[Regions][Countries] = ...;
float DG[Regions][Countries] = ...;
float DA[Regions][Countries] = ...;
float CG[Regions][Countries] = ...; 
float CA[Regions][Countries] = ...;
int MAX_BUDGET = ...;
float Threshold = ...;

// Decision variables
dvar int Region_Containers[Regions];//number of containers to send to region
dvar int GX[Regions][Countries]; // number of baskets transported by ground from region i to country j
dvar int AX[Regions][Countries]; // number of baskets transported by air from region i to country j
dvar int Threshold_Respected[]

maximize sum(i in Regions, j in Countries) ((GX[i][j]*(1-LG[i][j])*DG[i][j]) + (AX[i][j]*(1-LA[i][j])*DA[i][j]));

subject to{
  //Check that total number of baskets is respected
  sum(i in Regions, j in Countries) (GX[i][j] + AX[i][j]) <= MAX_BASKETS;
  //cant send more baskets than the needs
  forall(i in Regions, j in Countries)
    GX[i][j] + AX[i][j] <= Needs[i][j];
  
  //Ensures full container loads
  forall(i in Regions)
    sum(j in Countries) (GX[i][j] + AX[i][j]) == Region_Containers[i]*150;
  //Ensure budget is respect
  (   sum(i in Regions) Container_Cost_Transport[i]*Region_Containers[i] + sum(i in Regions,j in Countries) (GX[i][j]*CG[i][j] + AX[i][j]*CA[i][j])   )  <= MAX_BUDGET;
  // TODO: Constraint for emergency level threshold
}


I would use logical constraints.
range emergencylevels=1..3;

float available_food=400;

float food_needs[emergencylevels]=[100,200,300];

dvar float+ distribution_total[emergencylevels];

minimize sum(e in emergencylevels ) abs(distribution_total[e]-food_needs[e]);

subject to
{
  forall(e in emergencylevels:(e+1) in emergencylevels)
    (distribution_total[e+1]<=0.6*food_needs[e+1]) => (distribution_total[e]==0);
    
    sum(e in emergencylevels) distribution_total[e]<=available_food;
    
    //distribution_total[3]==100;
}

gives
distribution_total = [99.998 120 180];

but if I uncomment
//distribution_total[3]==100;

then the level3 does nor reach 60% and we get
distribution_total = [0 0  100];

